# Resize (don't crop) images for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, resize, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce cart for WordPress and am trying to get the images I upload for the thumbnails to be the aspect ratio i set it (270px × 200px) and not crop. See end of question for an image showing what I'm trying to achieve.

I don't want the image to be cropped, I want it to resize at a max height (200px) if it's tall or a max width (270px) if it's wide and center itself both vertically and horizontally into the thumbnail constraints (270px x 200px).

I've looked through all of the docs of both WordPress and WooCommerce and can't locate any way of achieving this natively.

I'm using wordpress v3.8.1. If this is not possible through WordPress or WooCommerce, do you know of any image resizer plugin that would do this type of cropping?

[image: examples of various image resize/crop styles]

Comment: http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com

Comment: It can be done, however using wordpress filters alone will give you a black background. A plugin like that would likely have to extend both the GD and/or Imagick PHP Classes, or rewrite the entire image saving process separately, which is quite a task either way.